# Filtering with Simple HTML Dom

Tags: html, dom, simple-html-dom

I am using SimpleHTMLDom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to parse a html page, on this page there are 2 types of < li > elements that I want to grab

```
<li class="g">SOME TEXT & LINKS HERE</li>

and 

<li class="g no-sep">SOME TEXT & LINKS HERE</li>
```

Is there any way that I can complete this using html dom currently I am using the following code to grab the two different li's however there is a cross over.

```
foreach($html->find('li.g h3 a') as $ul) 
{
             echo $ul->href."<br>";
}

foreach($html->find('li.no-sep h3 a') as $ul) 
{
             echo $ul->href."<br>";
}
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

This will grab all `<li>`s with *.g* class = `<li class="g">` and `<li class="g no-sep>`

```
foreach($html->find('li.g h3 a') as $ul) 
{
             echo $ul->href."<br>";
}
```

This will grab only those `<li>`s that have class *.g* AND *.no-sep* at the same time = only `<li class="g no-sep">`

```
foreach($html->find('li.g.no-sep h3 a') as $ul)
{
             echo $ul->href."<br>";
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This will grab all `<li>`s with *.g* class but skip those which also have a *.no-sep* class

```
foreach($html->find('.g') as $li) {
    if (!str_get_html($li)->find('.no-sep')) echo $li;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this would work like the current solution I need to be able to ignore no-sep when searching or atleast bring nosep back into the results

Comment: @KieranHeadley oh, sorry, misunderstood it. Look at the update... is it working for you now? :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can use [`Attribute Filters`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)... In your case try:

```
foreach($html->find('li[class!=no-sep] h3 a') as $ul) {
    echo $ul->href."<br>";
}
```

If it doesnt work (simple_html_dom has serious problems with filtering !), then you can use conditionals like:

```
foreach( $html->find('li.g') as $i=>$ul ) {
    if (strpos($ul->class,'no-sep') === false) {
        echo $ul->href."<br>";
    }
}
```